# $watch not triggering in directive after change in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, javascript-databinding

I have a directive which is basically just a countdown timer.  The usage is fairly simple,  start counting down whenever the `startFlag` is true, stop counting when it is false, and call the timeout function when time runs out:

```
app.directive('countdownTimer', [ '$interval', 
    function($interval) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/common/countdownTimer.html',
            scope: {
                timeAllotted: '=',
                startFlag: '=',
                timeoutCallback: '='
            },
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var timeLeft;

            // Set watch on time allotted
            scope.$watch('timeAllotted', function(newValue) {
                timeLeft = newValue;
                scope.minutes = getMinutes(timeLeft);
                scope.seconds = getSeconds(timeLeft);
            });

            // Set watch on start flag
            scope.$watch('startFlag', function(newValue) {
                if(newValue) {
                    scope.timer = $interval(tickFunction, 1000);
                } else {
                    $interval.cancel(scope.timer);
                }
            });

            function getFormattedTimeValue(val) {
                if(val < 10) {
                    val = '0' +  val;
                }
                return val;
            }

            function getMinutes(secs) {
                return getFormattedTimeValue(parseInt(secs / 60));
            }

            function getSeconds(secs) {
                return getFormattedTimeValue(secs % 60);
            }

            function tickFunction(triggerTimeout) {
                timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
                scope.minutes = getMinutes(timeLeft);
                scope.seconds = getSeconds(timeLeft);
                if(timeLeft <= 0) {
                    scope.timeoutCallback();
                    scope.startFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

My issue is that the watch on `timeAllotted` above works, but only the first time. It is  being set by a property of an object that is being loaded from a remote data source:

```
<countdown-timer
    data-time-allotted="vm.timeRemaining" 
    data-start-flag="vm.taskStarted" 
    data-timeout-callback="vm.taskTimeout">
</countdown-timer>
```

All of this works great.  The directive updates its local `timeLeft` variable properly when the data from `vm.timeRemaining` changes (it is initialized at 0 and then updated when the other object becomes available).

However, I wish to also offer the option of extending the time once the timeout condition occurs. But when I update `vm.timeRemaining` after the timeout condition, the `$watch` on the directive is not triggered.

This is my current attempt to update the time remaining from my controller:

```
function extendTime() {
    // This should reset the clock back to it's starting time, 
    // but it doesn't change!
    vm.timeRemaining = vm.task.time_limit;

    vm.hasAccess = true;
    dismissModal();

    // Added timeout so I could try $scope.$apply().. didn't help
    $timeout(function() {

        $scope.$apply();

        // This confirms that vm.timeRemaining is updating here, but the 
        // $watch on timeAllotted isn't firing in the directive
        console.log('timeRemaining updated');
        console.log(vm.timeRemaining);

        startTask();
    }, 50);

}
```

For what it's worth, the task timeout isn't doing too much that's interesting:

```
function taskTimeout() {
    // Cancels timer
    pauseTask();
    // Synchronizes data with API
    syncTick();
    // Opens a modal
    vm.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/common/timeoutModal.html',
        scope: $scope
    });
}
```

Any idea why updating `vm.timeRemaining` in my controller's `extendTime` function isn't being recognized from my directive's `$watch` on it's `timeAllotted` bound variable?

**Update**

Below is the function that is retrieving a task from my datacontext (it is basically just a container of repositories).  Once the promise is resolved, `vm.timeRemaining` is updated and, in this situation, is correctly `$watch`ed by the directive:

```
function getTask() {
    return datacontext.task.loadForLevel(level)
        .then(function(results) {
            vm.task = results[0];
            vm.timeRemaining = vm.task.time_limit;
        })
    ;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting confused between **timeAllotted** and **timeRemaining**? You never explicitly put a $watch on **timeRemaining** or declare it as a model in your $scope

Comment: timeAllotted is the scope variable referred to in the directive. It is correctly watching it (and the startFlag) after going through the task once, but won't watch when I update it later?

Comment: Put another way.. `timeAllotted` in the directive should be bound to the controller variable `vm.timeRemaining`, or is that incorrect?

Comment: @watcher I am having the same issue. So one variable in my controller gets updated after making an API request. This variable change is reflected in my directive if I access that variable. But I want to copy some part of that variable to my directive local variable and so have put a watch on this controller variable as $watch(scope.variableName) but watch won't run and wont update my local variable with that. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Keshav nope, for me it turned out to be a non-issue because we moved away and started working on other things. I am still interested though in figuring out what I was doing wrong!